# Why are Borrow and AsRef implemented differently?

Tags: rust

The `Borrow` and `AsRef` traits are very similar in Rust. If I understand correctly, they have the exact same signature (except for the method name) when being implemented on the same type, the difference lies in how they are used.

But when you take a look at their implementation, for instance on `Vec<T>` there is a subtle difference:

[slice.rs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/slice.rs.html#709-713):

```
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl<T> Borrow<[T]> for Vec<T> {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &[T] {
        &self[..]
    }
}
```

[vec.rs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#2356-2360):

```
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl<T> AsRef<[T]> for Vec<T> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &[T] {
        self
    }
}
```

I believe the implementation of `AsRef` here works thanks to `Deref` coercion. But couldn't the same mechanism be used for the `Borrow` implementation?

Comment: I've been screwing around with this -- still not sure why the implementations are different here, but I can confirm your theory about the Deref coercion powering the AsRef implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure whether your question can be answered at all. There isn't necessarily a reason for which two functions that do the same thing are written *slightly* differently. After all, in general, there isn't a single way to write the same code.

Comment: They [were](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/23538) [written](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/18910) by different people at different times (and `Borrow` is older). Isn't that enough?

Comment: I believe that the `AsRef` implementation is saying: "Give a reference to the underlying slice". Meanwhile, the `Borrow` implementation is saying: "Borrow the subslice `..` (ie. all the elements) from the vector. That being said, the difference is either semantic OR needed to let the compiler know that in `Borrow` you are borrowing a subslice rather than the vector itself.

Comment: For future readers looking for the practical difference between the `AsRef` and `Borrow` traits, there's some useful insight in the answers here: [Why does T not implement AsRef<T>?](/q/48887413/2189130)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no practical difference between the two implementations.

You are correct in your assessment of the semantic differences: the `&self[..]` body uses the index operator with an open range to create a slice of the entire vector, while the basic `self` body relies on [`Deref` coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#more-on-deref-coercion) where the compiler automatically converts `&Vec<T>` to `&[T]`.

There is no functional difference. As you've noted, the method signatures are identical and thus are identical to the borrow checker outside the implementation. A comment above suggests an internal difference between borrowing the vector and borrowing a slice from that vector, but that is not the case; in both the slice's lifetime is derived from `self`. The generated assembly for both methods are also identical; although they use different ways to get the same result and optimizations are sometimes chaotic, I'd be surprised if there were any code-generation difference in any situation.

So the only difference is that of style. Both these implementations have existed as they are since before the Rust 1.0 release. As a comment above mentions, the `Borrow` implementation is older and while the `Deref` trait did *exist* at the time of its writing, it was only freshly implemented for `Vec`s (a month prior) and was not finalized until months later. So it is not surprising that the original `Borrow` implementation used the pre-deref syntax. The `AsRef` implementation did not exist until after `Deref` was finalized, so it is not surprising the author used it.

So the differences that you see are inconsequential and historical only.

Answer (score 1):

One site gives a really helpful answer:

> We can see how they’re kind of the same: they both deal with owned and
> borrowed versions of some type. However, they’re a bit different.
>
> Choose `Borrow` when you want to abstract over different kinds of
> borrowing, or when you’re building a data structure that treats owned
> and borrowed values in equivalent ways, such as hashing and
> comparison.
>
> Choose `AsRef` when you want to convert something to a reference
> directly, and you’re writing generic code.

—[Source](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/first-edition/borrow-and-asref.html)